# CodeIgniter v3 + Smarty v3 SmartyCompilerException Error at form validation time

Tags: codeigniter, validation, smarty

An uncaught Exception was encountered

```
Type: SmartyCompilerException

Message: Syntax error in template **"/home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/views/templates/registration/registration.tpl"
 on line 96 "
[~ci_form_validation field='email'~]
" unknown tag "ci_form_validation"**

Filename: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php

Line Number: 96

Backtrace:

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
Line: 687
Function: trigger_template_error

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
Line: 457
Function: compileTag2

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php
Line: 1395
Function: compileTag

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php
Line: 2265
Function: yy_r33

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php
Line: 2360
Function: yy_reduce

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_smartytemplatecompiler.php
Line: 114
Function: doParse

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
Line: 391
Function: doCompile

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php
Line: 226
Function: compileTemplate

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php
Line: 152
Function: compileTemplateSource

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php
Line: 199
Function: process

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php
Line: 246
Function: render

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/third_party/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php
Line: 820
Function: render

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/libraries/Asoft_smarty.php
Line: 63
Function: fetch

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/UsedVala/controllers/Usedvala.php
Line: 94
Function: view

File: /home/usedvala/public_html/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

**Please help me how to solve this problem:-)**

Comment: Impossible task without any code ;-) Please edit question, format correctly, and show us a snippet demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to read the error. The template is trying to call a function named ci_form_validation that doesn't exists in your installation. You probably forgot to put some files in your smarty plugin's folder